# Could we create & export a map of our facebook friends network?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, networking, hyperlink, cartography

I have a question about Facebook's capabilities. Does it give the access to the connections between friend?

For example I have a professional account where I have 100 friends, and I would like to export a map where I will see the connection between each other, like a wheel with me in the centre.

Friend A, knows B, E, R.
Friend B, knows A, E, V, W, Y
Friend C, knows V & Y
Etc.

Each letter are in my 100 friends.

In doing this I will quickly see if some people in my network know others and we could create business opportunities.

If you know another system which can create a big global map with all of my friends, please let me know. I will have a lot of data but I could clean it. Lots is better than less.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this and a slew of other data like this from the Open Graph API provided by facebook.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

It will be up to you do the drawing and data plotting. Remember though, your API key is going to have a rate limit I think, so you have to be smart about mining that much data.